# MVC: How can I make sure that my field have the value selected inside my view on the edit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3-Viewmodel on my project.

I have a create and edit form, What I am trying to do is to make sure that after a user Create a form, he/she should be able to edit it, when the user is at the edit page I want the values to be displayed in the inputs and selects. The only field that is not working is my DropDownList. I have no idea why.

If I close the application and go to the edit form I want that the DropDownList have the value that was created.

here is the code:

```
foreach (SelectedQuestionViewModel items in Model.AllSelectedQuestions)
{  

 <select id="selectstyle2" class="Grade">
 @{
  <option>n/a</option>
  int Grade = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
     <option @(items.Grade.HasValue && items.Grade.Value == Grade ? "selected" : "") >@(i)</option>
    }
  }
 </select>
}
```

any help kind of help is appreciated.

note: I use a ajax post to my controller, inside the controller I fill my "Model.Grade" with the value that was selected from this DDL.

Answer (score 0):

You have your select tag *within* your foreach loop.  Write this tag outside, like this:

```
<select>
@foreach(var x in Model)
   //write out options
</select>
```

also have a look at Html.DropDownList extension method.  This does what you're trying to do by hand.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx

as an example

```
@{
    var selectListItems = (new[] { 1,2,3}).Select(i=>new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.AllSelectedQuestions[0].Grade, selectListItems, "n/a")
```

Comment: I cant do that, beacuse I have a bunch of other fields inside the foreach

Comment: You can do this, but it would be a different foreach loop. You could dynamically create a collection of SelectListItem (I'd probably make this static somewhere so it can be reused for each AllSelectedQuestion), then, use the Helper extension as mentioned.

Comment: @RammtinAvar I see what you mean, I misread your question. Still do have a look at the `Html.DropDownList` method and its overloads.  It does what you're trying to do.  Have you verified that your "selected" string is getting written out right?

Comment: the thing I need a client-side dropdownlist with option 1-10.. Is it possible to do that with DropDownList?

Comment: The Html Helper is an ASP.NET MVC class that renders HTML into your view.  The same way that you can use foreach loops in your view and get client side HTML, this does it.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I have only passed models in html helpers

Comment: I updated my answer with a rough cut of what the code would look like.